# Java: Object moving on a path, ignores certain coordinates. How to fix?

Tags: java

I have a circle that moves from point A to a random point B. When the object nears point B, a new random target location gets chosen. If the circle is moving parallel to the X-axis or Y-axis the object goes through all the pixels in the way and leaves a solid trace. But if the circle moves diagonally, it skips pixels and shakes slightly, making the animation not smooth and leaves a trace with unpainted pixels.

My algorithm is:

1. calculate the X and Y distances
2. check if the circle is near
3. if so, choose the new destination
4. if 2. is true, find the real distance using Pythagoras' theorem
5. if 2. is true, calculate the X and Y speed (the change of the coordinates)
6. set the new coordinates (no matter if 2. is true or not)

And here is the code:

```
  public void move ()//движение
  {
      //finds the X and Y distance to the destination
      int triangleX = nextLocationX - coorX;
      int triangleY = nextLocationY - coorY;
      //if too near the coordinates of the destination changes
      if (Math.abs(triangleX) <= Math.abs(speedX) || Math.abs(triangleY) <= Math.abs(speedY))//setting the new target
      {
          //setting the new destinatio
          int randInt;
          for (;;)//I don't want the the new destination to be that same spot
          {
              randInt= randGen.nextInt(appletX);
              if (randInt != nextLocationX)
              {
                  nextLocationX = randInt + radius;
                  break;
              }
          }
          for (;;)
          {
              randInt = randGen.nextInt(appletY);
              if (randInt != nextLocationY)
              {
                  nextLocationY = randInt + radius;
                  break;
              }
          }
          //calculating the change of the circle's X and Y coordinates
          triangleX = nextLocationX - coorX;
          triangleY = nextLocationY - coorY;
          speedX = ((double)(speed * triangleX) / (Math.sqrt (Math.pow(triangleX, 2) + Math.pow(triangleY, 2))));
          speedY = ((double)(speed * triangleY) / (Math.sqrt (Math.pow(triangleX, 2) + Math.pow(triangleY, 2))));
      }
      //the realCoor variables are from type double
      //they are the exact coordinates of the circle
      //If I only use integers, the circle almost
      //never reaches it's destination
      //unless the change of the coordinates gets calculated
      //after every time they change
      realCoorX = realCoorX + speedX;
      realCoorY = realCoorY + speedY;
      coorX = (int)Math.round(realCoorX);
      coorY = (int)Math.round(realCoorY);
  }
```

I suspect that the problem is in the calculation of the change of the coordinates.

Comment: I see what I was misunderstanding, thanks for clarifying.  Algorithm looks correct in that case, I think.  I'd guess one of two issues (or, kinda sounds like both).  Possibly a precision issue, low resolution could make movement noticeably less smooth when moving diagonally, where movement isn't as easily quantized for display.  Second, would be redrawing issues, which depending on implementation can flicker or leave traces of the previous animation frame behind.  In that case, [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) could help.

Comment: I use the traces for debugging by updating the image. I also have a line that connects the coordinates of the circle with the coordinates of the current destination- when updating the image, the line gets thicker. Yeah... The problem should be in the precision.

Answer (score 0):

For me this sounds like a Aliasing problem. You would have the same problem if you draw(!) a line that is not aligned with the coordinate axis. As you know, i.e. diagonal lines need "half filled" pixels to look smooth.

Solution for you would be (depending on the technology for rendering) to use floating point position calculation.